# Printing statement does not provide me with accurate numbers

Tags: python, while-loop, formatting, sum, average

Ok here's the problem, the code works, but the numbers dont add up right, so im missing something somewhere. My brain is absolutely dead from working on this for three days straight so i need another set of eyes. Basically this is a grading calculator that takes input from a .txt file and sends output to a .txt file. I am dropping the lowest quiz score. I also need a little help with the outfile.write(outstring) formatting, it's all over the place right now and i need it to look exactly like the output file. Im leaving in some diagnostic print statements but essentially this is what the code looks like right now:

```
infilename = input("Please enter file name: ")
outfilename = input("Please enter output file name: ")

infile = open(infilename,"r")
outfile = open(outfilename, "w")

quiz_sum = 0
low_quiz = 1000
prog_sum = 0

nameline = infile.readline()
outfile.write(nameline)
print(nameline)
while nameline != "":
    quiz_line = infile.readline()
    prog_line = infile.readline()
    exam_line = infile.readline()
    quiz_list=quiz_line.split()
    quiz_sum = 0
    prog_sum = 0
    low_quiz = 1000
    for quiz_score in quiz_list:
        quiz_float = float(quiz_score)
        quiz_sum += quiz_float
        if quiz_float < low_quiz:
            low_quiz = quiz_float
    if len(quiz_list) > 1:
        quiz_avg = ((quiz_sum-low_quiz)/(len(quiz_list)-1))*10
    else:
        quiz_avg = quiz_sum*10
    print("QUIZ AVERAGE", quiz_avg)
    prog_list = prog_line.split()
    for prog_score in prog_list:
        prog_float = float(prog_score)
        prog_sum += prog_float
    if len(prog_list) > 1:
        prog_avg = ((prog_sum) / len(prog_list))*10
    else:
        prog_avg = prog_sum*10
    print("PROGRAM AVERAGE", prog_avg)
    exam_list = exam_line.split()
    for exam_score in exam_list:
        exam_float = float(exam_score)
        #exam_sum += exam_float
    exam1 = float(exam_list[0])
    exam2 = float(exam_list[1])
    exam3 = float(exam_list[2])
    exam_avg = (exam1*.20)+(exam2*.20)+(exam3*.25)
    print("EXAMs" , exam1,exam2,exam3)
    average = ((quiz_avg*.15)+(prog_avg*.20)+(exam_avg))
    if 90 <= average <= 100:
        final_grade = "A"
    if 80 <= average < 90:
        final_grade = "B"
    if 70 <= average < 80:
        final_grade = "C"
    if 60 <= average < 70:
        final_grade = "D"
    if 0 <= average < 60:
        final_grade = "F"
    print("TOTAL AVERAGE",average)
    outstring =("%-20s %3.1f   %s" %(nameline,average,final_grade))
    print(outstring)
    outfile.write(outstring)
    nameline = infile.readline()
    outstring = ("%-20s***" % (nameline))

infile.close()
outfile.close()
```

Here is what the input will look like (1st row of numbers are quizzes, second is program projects, and third are exams [exam1,2,3 respectively]):

```
Babbage, Charles
10.0   9.5    8.0  9.0
 9.5  10.0    9.0
85.0  92.0   81.0
Turing, Alan
1.0   8.0    6.0
10.0  10.0    9.0   9.5
90.0  92.0   88.5
Hopper, Grace
10.0  5.0    8.0
10.0  10.0    9.0   9.5
90.0  92.0   88.0
Van Rossum, Guido
 7.5   8.5
 7.5   6.0    6.0   9.0
68.0  81.0   70.0
Backus, John
 9.5   3   10.0   8.0   9.5  10.0
 7.5   8.5    6.0   9.0  10.0
99.0  93.0  44.0
Crawley, Bryan
 6.0
 7.5
70.0  60.0   55.5
```

And finally this is what is supposed to be the formatting of the output:

```
Babbage, Charles      89.4   B
Turing, Alan          91.3   A
Hopper, Grace         92.7   A
Van Rossum, Guido     75.5   C
Backus, John          94.4   A
Crawley, Bryan        63.9   D
```

tl;dr - I need to get the right numbers for the averages for this program to work. I also need help with the format for how the program writes to the file at the end of the loop. Thanks guys.

EDIT -

Updating post to show what happens when i run the program:
    Please enter file name: scores.txt
    Please enter output file name: results.txt
    Babbage, Charles

```
QUIZ AVERAGE 95.0
PROGRAM AVERAGE 95.0
EXAMs 85.0 92.0 81.0
TOTAL AVERAGE 88.9
Babbage, Charles
    88.9   B
QUIZ AVERAGE 70.0
PROGRAM AVERAGE 96.25
EXAMs 90.0 92.0 88.5
TOTAL AVERAGE 88.275
Turing, Alan
        88.3   B
QUIZ AVERAGE 90.0
PROGRAM AVERAGE 96.25
EXAMs 90.0 92.0 88.0
TOTAL AVERAGE 91.15
Hopper, Grace
       91.2   A
QUIZ AVERAGE 85.0
PROGRAM AVERAGE 71.25
EXAMs 68.0 81.0 70.0
TOTAL AVERAGE 74.3
Van Rossum, Guido
   74.3   C
QUIZ AVERAGE 94.0
PROGRAM AVERAGE 82.0
EXAMs 99.0 93.0 44.0
TOTAL AVERAGE 79.9
Backus, John
        79.9   C
QUIZ AVERAGE 60.0
PROGRAM AVERAGE 75.0
EXAMs 70.0 60.0 55.5
TOTAL AVERAGE 63.875
Crawley, Bryan
      63.9   D
```

And this is what is in the "results.txt" file:

```
Babbage, Charles
Babbage, Charles
    88.9   BTuring, Alan
        88.3   BHopper, Grace
       91.2   AVan Rossum, Guido
   74.3   CBackus, John
        79.9   CCrawley, Bryan
      63.9   D
```

Comment: What's inaccurate about these numbers?

Comment: What output do you get with your current code?

Comment: updated the post! thanks guys. @Isaac Saffold

Comment: @user2357112 check the post again, if you compare my output to the results that im supposed to be getting you'll see that they are all a few points off.

Comment: Sounds to me like you're simply performing the wrong computation. Reread the problem spec. (We don't have the problem spec, so we can't help you with that.)

Comment: the spec is dropping the lowest quiz grade, then quizes are 15 percent, programs are 20 percent, and the first two exams are 20 percent and the last exam is 25 percent. Ive redone the computation ten times now and nothing is changing, cant figure it out. Any ideas on the formatting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
infilename = input("Please enter file name: ")
outfilename = input("Please enter output file name: ")

infile = open(infilename,"r")
outfile = open(outfilename, "w")

quiz_sum = 0
low_quiz = 1000
prog_sum = 0

nameline = infile.readline()
# outfile.write(nameline) # no need to have this
# print(nameline)
while nameline != "":
    quiz_line = infile.readline()
    prog_line = infile.readline()
    exam_line = infile.readline()
    quiz_list=quiz_line.split()
    quiz_sum = 0
    prog_sum = 0
    low_quiz = 1000
    for quiz_score in quiz_list:
        quiz_float = float(quiz_score)
        quiz_sum += quiz_float
        if quiz_float < low_quiz:
            low_quiz = quiz_float
    if len(quiz_list) > 1:
        quiz_avg = ((quiz_sum-low_quiz)/(len(quiz_list)-1))*10
    else:
        quiz_avg = quiz_sum*10
    print("QUIZ AVERAGE", quiz_avg)
    prog_list = prog_line.split()
    for prog_score in prog_list:
        prog_float = float(prog_score)
        prog_sum += prog_float
    if len(prog_list) > 1:
        prog_avg = ((prog_sum) / len(prog_list))*10
    else:
        prog_avg = prog_sum*10
    print("PROGRAM AVERAGE", prog_avg)
    exam_list = exam_line.split()
    for exam_score in exam_list:
        exam_float = float(exam_score)
        #exam_sum += exam_float
    exam1 = float(exam_list[0])
    exam2 = float(exam_list[1])
    exam3 = float(exam_list[2])
    exam_avg = (exam1*.20)+(exam2*.20)+(exam3*.25)
    print("EXAMs" , exam1,exam2,exam3)
    average = ((quiz_avg*.15)+(prog_avg*.20)+(exam_avg))
    if 90 <= average and average <= 100:
        final_grade = "A"
    if 80 <= average and average < 90:
        final_grade = "B"
    if 70 <= average and average < 80:
        final_grade = "C"
    if 60 <= average and average < 70:
        final_grade = "D"
    if 0 <= average and average < 60:
        final_grade = "F"
    print("TOTAL AVERAGE",average)
    outstring = ("{0:<20} {1:<8} {2:<25}\n".format(nameline.strip(), round(average,1), final_grade))
    print(outstring)
    outfile.write(outstring)
    nameline = infile.readline()
    outstring = ("%-20s***" % (nameline))

infile.close()
outfile.close()
```

I have fixed output formatting. Now it looks like following.

result output file:

```
Babbage, Charles     88.9     B                        
Turing, Alan         88.3     B                        
Hopper, Grace        91.2     A                        
Van Rossum, Guido    74.3     C                        
Backus, John         79.9     C                        
Crawley, Bryan       63.9     D
```

consolt output:

```
('QUIZ AVERAGE', 95.0)
('PROGRAM AVERAGE', 95.0)
('EXAMs', 85.0, 92.0, 81.0)
('TOTAL AVERAGE', 88.9)
Babbage, Charles     88.9     B                        

('QUIZ AVERAGE', 70.0)
('PROGRAM AVERAGE', 96.25)
('EXAMs', 90.0, 92.0, 88.5)
('TOTAL AVERAGE', 88.275)
Turing, Alan         88.3     B                        

('QUIZ AVERAGE', 90.0)
('PROGRAM AVERAGE', 96.25)
('EXAMs', 90.0, 92.0, 88.0)
('TOTAL AVERAGE', 91.15)
Hopper, Grace        91.2     A                        

('QUIZ AVERAGE', 85.0)
('PROGRAM AVERAGE', 71.25)
('EXAMs', 68.0, 81.0, 70.0)
('TOTAL AVERAGE', 74.3)
Van Rossum, Guido    74.3     C                        

('QUIZ AVERAGE', 94.0)
('PROGRAM AVERAGE', 82.0)
('EXAMs', 99.0, 93.0, 44.0)
('TOTAL AVERAGE', 79.9)
Backus, John         79.9     C                        

('QUIZ AVERAGE', 60.0)
('PROGRAM AVERAGE', 75.0)
('EXAMs', 70.0, 60.0, 55.5)
('TOTAL AVERAGE', 63.875)
Crawley, Bryan       63.9     D
```

I can work on grade calculation if you can provide question how to calculate(separate question would be recommended).

Comment: Thanks so much! So the formula to calculate the average is as follows: first thing is to drop the lowest quiz grade, then quizzes are worth 15 percent [ first line of numbers], programs are 20 percent[second line of numbers], and the first two exams are 20 percent and the last exam is 25 percent[third line]. Ive redone the computation ten times now and nothing is changing, cant figure it out. Here is an image of the assignment for weighted average: https://imgur.com/a/hTSrP

Comment: Did that comment make sense @mahesh karia?

Comment: dumb move on my part, realized that I had two separate score.txt files with different values and the program actually works perfectly. Thanks again, marked your answer correct for the fix on the formatting.